# Write own Javascript plugins for creating audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I write my own Javascript plugins for creating an audio player.
I  created one in the AudioPlayer.js file:

```
(function ($) {
                jQuery.fn.myPlayer = function (options) {
                var defaults = {
                    id: "#myPlayer",
                    url: ""
                };

                var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

                return this.each(function () {
                    var AudioPlayer = $("<audio>");
                    AudioPlayer.attr('id', settings.id);
                    AudioPlayer.attr('controls', 'true');
                    AudioPlayer.appendTo(this);
                    var source = $("<source>");
                    source.attr('src', settings.url);
                    source.attr('type', 'audio/mp3');
                    source.appendTo(AudioPlayer);
                });

            }

}(jQuery));
```

Above code is in AudioPlayer.js, and add this reference to a "HTML" page, and
Now I am accessing this file in html page like this:

```
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.playerDemo').myPlayer({
                        id: "myAudio",
                        url: "https://vzstr.blob.core.windows.net/media/e2d4255c-a03a-45ac-b34a-42bd3101f902/59006.mp3"
                    });
                });

        </script>
```

Using above code my player will display on browser, 
and I have two buttons one for play audio and second for paused audio,
how can achieve this functionality using Javascript plugins.
I want to write method for "PLAY" and "PAUSE" method in Javascript plugins.

How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Write this code in AudioPlayer.js file.
(function ($) {

    jQuery.fn.myPlayer = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            id: "#myPlayer",
            url: ""
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            var AudioPlayer = $("<audio>");
            AudioPlayer.attr('id', settings.id);
            AudioPlayer.attr('controls', 'true');
            AudioPlayer.appendTo(this);
            var source = $("<source>");
            source.attr('src', settings.url);
            source.attr('type', 'audio/mp3');
            source.appendTo(AudioPlayer);

            var AuPlayer = AudioPlayer[0];
            return {
                play: function () {
                    AuPlayer.play();
                },
                pause: function () {
                    AuPlayer.pause();
                }
            }
    }

}(jQuery));

Bellow code in HTML File,
<script>
        var playerDemo;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            playerDemo = $('.playerDemo').myPlayer({
                id: "myAudio",
                url: "https://vzstr.blob.core.windows.net/media/e2d4255c-a03a-45ac-b34a-42bd3101f902/59006.mp3"
            });
        });
        function playAudio() {
        playerDemo.play();
    }
    </script>
```